# omniauth-facebook can't convert nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

```
fb = OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook.new("app_id", "app_secret")
client = OAuth2::Client.new("app_id", "app_secret", fb.options.client_options) 
token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client,'access_token', fb.options.access_token_options)
fb.instance_variable_set("@access_token", token) 
fb.auth_hash
```

When I attempt to access the auth_hash, I get:

```
can't convert nil into String
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually, changing the first line to:

```
fb = OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook.new(nil, "app_id", "app_secret")
```

fixed the issue. I'm not sure what the first parameter represents.